# SQL need groups

Tags: sql, arrays, join, grouping

I want to group unique rows from 1 table that may have many rows in table 2.

If I do make this query:

```
SELECT c.`lastname`,a.`city`
FROM `customer` c
LEFT JOIN `visit` a ON (c.`id` = a.`id`);
```

I get results like this:

```
lastname |city
-------- |----
DOE      |Paris 
DOE      |Miami
Technical|Toronto
Technical|d
M        |toronto
mavya    |TORONTO
lname    |NULL
```

(Both `customer` and `visit` tables also have `id`s that I'm joining, but not showing here).

**How can I get results like below?** (Can I get SQL to return an array inside results?)

```
lastname |city
-------- |----
DOE      |Paris,Miami
Technical|Toronto,d
M        |toronto
mavya    |TORONTO
lname    |NULL
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your syntax, I am guessing that you are using MySQL (or SQLite).

In either, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT c.lastname, GROUP_CONCAT(v.`city`)
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     visit v
     ON c.id = v.id
GROUP BY c.lastname;
```

Comment: I knew is was simple. And thanks I now have enough reputation to up-vote answers